# How I can update two different Mysql tables from android with one async task?

Tags: android, mysql, asynchronous

I want to update two Mysql tables with one async task and different params, when save button is clicked. It's working properly when its about one table.. How do I implement such a thing?

The code on doInBackground() is:

```
// getting updated data 
            Log.d("aa for save", String.valueOf(aa));
            Log.d("bb for save", String.valueOf(bb));
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, p_id));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_aa, String.valueOf(aa)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_bb, String.valueOf(bb)));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,"POST", params);


        // getting updated data 

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params_user = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params_user.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_UNAME, uname));
            params_user.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_aa, String.valueOf(aa)));
            params_user.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_bb, String.valueOf(bb)));

            JSONObject json_user = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_user_votes,"POST", params_user);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                int success2 = json_user.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1 && success2 ==1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update 
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The error I get is :
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager"
 on the activity that has the onActivityResult()

Comment: Are you using startActivityForResult() while starting this activity ? and who do you want to notify with the success result ? The last activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Change two mysql tables in one php script and send success and succes2 in one json from servera

```
        // getting updated data 
        Log.d("aa for save", String.valueOf(aa));
        Log.d("bb for save", String.valueOf(bb));
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, p_id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_UNAME, uname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_aa, String.valueOf(aa)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_bb, String.valueOf(bb)));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_all,"POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            int success2 = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS2);

            if (success == 1 && success2 ==1) {
                // successfully updated
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about update
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to update 
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

example php script

```
<?php

$aa = $_REQUEST['aa'];
$bb = $_REQUEST['bb'];
$p_id = $_REQUEST['p_id'];
$uname = $_REQUEST['uname'];


//db connect.......

$success=0;
$resttt = "UPDATE table1 SET aa='$aa' ";
$result = mysql_query("$resttt");
if($result) { $success=1; }

$success2=0;
$resttt2 = "UPDATE table2 SET bb='$bb' ";
$result2 = mysql_query("$resttt2");
if($result2) { $success2=1; }


// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// success
$response["success"] = $success;
$response["success2"] = $success2;


// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Any example of php script?